# Attribute with no obvious entity

Tags: data-modeling

I have been working with a few others recently on a data model and they have some practices which seem wrong to me.  Here is one I would like to get your opinion on.
There is a concept in the reporting layer of the data warehouse called Rolled Balance Amount  which is to be computed at run time based on the Balance Amount over a period. It will be calculated at run time and rolled up for any one of a half dozen entities and classification hierarchies and date ranges.  In my opinion this is not a candidate to be in the Business data model at all (its underlying value there as Balance Amount) but because it is not an attribute of any single entity but my associates want to put is on "any Entity or maybe create a Reporting Results entity" to have it somewhere.
Am I being stubborn in trying to keep it out of the Business Data Model?
Thanks,
Pat.

Answer (score 1):

Modeling is modeling, not exact science.  The notion of some computed/derived results can indeed be crucial enough to include the notion in a "business" model.  (Problem then becomes making clear its "derived" nature as opposed to the "core" nature of other components of the model.)  You will know if you present your model to the managers and they keep asking "where are the derived results that we find so important" and you keep answering "they are not mentioned in this model because they are not part of the core data" and it doesn't help one bit.  Models are a means to communicate to an audience, and what exactly should be communicated depends on that audience's interests.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful answer.  I guess I have been guilty the mistake of ignoring the "business" nature of the model in favour of the system which we are going to produce.